# Not able to run Cucumber using Testng.But if i execute in Feature file it is working

Tags: java, cucumber, testng

In TestNg Runner i am not exectue code,but using feature file i am getting result

I need to execute using TestNg runner.Displaying below error

```
[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
  Options:
    -alwaysrunlisteners
      Should MethodInvocation Listeners be run even for skipped methods
      Default: true
    -configfailurepolicy
      Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
    -d
      Output directory
    -dataproviderthreadcount
      Number of threads to use when running data providers
    -dependencyinjectorfactory
      The dependency injector factory implementation that TestNG should use.
    -excludegroups
      Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
    -failwheneverythingskipped
      Should TestNG fail execution if all tests were skipped and nothing was 
      run. 
      Default: false
    -generateResultsPerSuite
      Should TestNG consider failures in Data Providers  as test failures.
      Default: false
    -groups
      Comma-separated list of group names to be run
    -ignoreMissedTestNames
      Ignore missed test names given by '-testnames' and continue to run 
      existing tests, if any.
      Default: false
    -includeAllDataDrivenTestsWhenSkipping
      Should TestNG report all iterations of a data driven test as individual 
      skips, in-case of upstream failures.
      Default: false
    -junit
      JUnit mode
      Default: false
    -listener
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener 
      or ISuiteListener
    -methods
      Comma separated of test methods
      Default: []
    -methodselectors
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
    -mixed
      Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with 
      appropriate runner
      Default: false
    -objectfactory
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing 
      ITestRunnerFactory 
    -overrideincludedmethods
      Comma separated fully qualified class names of listeners that should be 
      skipped from being wired in via Service Loaders.
      Default: false
    -parallel
      Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
      Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none]
    -port
      The port
    -propagateDataProviderFailureAsTestFailure
      Should TestNG consider failures in Data Providers  as test failures.
      Default: false
    -reporter
      Extended configuration for custom report listener
    -spilistenerstoskip
      Comma separated fully qualified class names of listeners that should be 
      skipped from being wired in via Service Loaders.
      Default: <empty string>
    -suitename
      Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or 
      source code
    -suitethreadpoolsize
      Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
      Default: 1
    -testclass
      The list of test classes
    -testjar
      A jar file containing the tests
    -testname
      Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source 
      code 
    -testnames
      The list of test names to run
    -testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
      The factory used to create tests
    -threadcount
      Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
    -threadpoolfactoryclass
      The threadpool executor factory implementation that TestNG should use.
    -usedefaultlisteners
      Whether to use the default listeners
      Default: true
    -log, -verbose
      Level of verbosity
    -xmlpathinjar
      The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if 
      -testjar was specified)
      Default: testng.xml
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample that can be used to reproduce your issue? You could upload the sample into github and share the link by editing your question. The error you are seeing is TestNG's way of telling you that TestNG did not detect any test methods to execute.

Answer (score 0):

To run Cucumber features by TestNG make sure that the following steps are fulfilled:

1. Cucumber-testNG dependency is included: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng
2. Cucumber runner class is be created, e.g.:

```
    package testrunners;

    import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
    import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

    @CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/test/resources/features",
            glue = {"stepdefinitions"},
            plugin = {
                    "pretty",
                    "json:cucumber.json"
            }
    )
    public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {}
```

The class must extend the **AbstractTestNGCucumberTests** class
**src/test/resources/features** is the path to the folder with your .feature files
**stepdefinitions** is the package's name where classes with the code for the implemented steps are located.

3. TestNG XML runs the Cucumber runner class from the step above, e.g.:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Default Suite" configfailurepolicy="continue" time- 
    out="60000">
        <test name="Main tests">
            <classes>
                <class name="testrunners.TestRunner"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

With this setup you should be able to run the TestNG XML, which will execute all scenarios, from all .feature files located in the specified folder.